# netbeans 8.2 shows warnings on start up

Tags: netbeans-8

I download netbeans 8.2 for benefit recents lasts updates, I install it and I install my usual plugins, after finishing plugin installations everything it works but my problem is the following warnings that netbeans shows me when it starts:

[image: warning01] 
[image: warning02]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be a problem with your cache. I'm not too sure if you can clear the cache of Netbeans. However, try repairing the program, and if that doesn't work, then backup your projects and re-install Netbeans, as there may have been a problem with your download and installation.